# How to Set the relative path; Static files are working perfectly on localhost but not getting loaded while deploying django application on AWS EB

Tags: django, amazon-web-services

[this is the file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tuMzu.jpg)

the static files are present in firstproject/music/static/ folder on the local machine.

on EB environment, the path to static files is:
    /home/ubuntu/firstproject/music/static/`

In settings.py, I have written:

```
STATIC_ROOT = '/home/ubuntu/moodyteens/music/static/'

STATIC_URL = '/music/static/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media') # it is the original path where                  file is being saved.

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'  # it is the reference given to the path.
```

In urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
url(r'^music/', include('music.urls')),
url(r'^', include('music.urls')),
]

if settings.DEBUG: 
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL,          document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

and I am using the static files in base.html as:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="{% static 'favicon.ico'        %}"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'music/style.css'%}"    />
<script src="{% static 'music/js/main.js'%}"></script>
```

How to set the relative path of the static files? Why static files are working perfectly on localhost but not on the AWS EB environment?

I have also run the 'python manage.py collectstatic' on server side.

Comment: I don't know AWS EB, but maybe you need to specify a full URL in STATIC_URL. See http://djangodeployment.com/2016/11/21/how-django-static-files-work-in-production/ to understand how static files work.

Comment: Hey Antonis, I have tried this thing also. But its not working.